# os.rename giving an error

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to have my code look for specific files, then rename them with my newName which I defined elsewhere.  I am trying to debug this code, but I cannot think of what I am doing wrong when trying to implement the os.rename. I have see the SRC and DST as os.path.joins in other solutions I've found on stackoverflow. Can anyone provide any insight?

```
if os.path.exists(curr_dir + '\\Output\\Fab'):
        for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(curr_dir + '\Output\Fab'):
            for f in files:
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
                newName = replacement + ext
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, newName )
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You escape your backslashes in the first line, but not the second. You should probably do it on both lines.

Comment: Also, in the line you provide, you're missing an end parentheses.

Comment: Try printing `os.path.join(path, newName )` to see if it's ok. The same for f.

Comment: It does print the new path exactly as I'm expecting.

Comment: I feel a bit rosy-cheeked.  I didn't even notice that some of the characters within the strings I'm attempting to use as file names are illegal file name characters in Windows.  My example newName includes "????."

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you get an error if the destination file allready exists.

Use '/' instead of '\' so it doesn't escape the next char.

On the second line you use `\` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Thank you.  I made everything a \\ and I just forgot to copy in the end parentheses.  I am receiving the error on the last line and it is:  [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.